# Как запустить Postgres в Docker-контейнере (WARNING: Host is already in use by another container)

Tags: intellij-idea, docker, docker-compose

Установил Docker и Docker Compose:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в корне проекта в папке docker создаю файл docker-compose.yml:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое файла docker-compose.yml:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее пытаюсь запустить контейнер, но выпадает ошибка:

> Deploying 'Compose: docker'...
>
> docker-compose -f
> "/mnt/541d54bf-8e57-464d-9e77-b8676fc83fdb/_temp/.../hibernate-app/docker/docker-compose.yml"
> up -d db
>
> Starting ffea8a86d792_docker_db_1 ...
>
> WARNING: Host is already in use by another container
>
> Starting ffea8a86d792_docker_db_1 ... error
>
> ERROR: for ffea8a86d792_docker_db_1  Cannot start service db: driver
> failed programming external connectivity on endpoint
> ffea8a86d792_docker_db_1
> (3b0c5cf0437b75725d98b732640a6e2efaa84fdcdad46700f8a7665caae23fae):
> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address
> already in use
>
> ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming
> external connectivity on endpoint ffea8a86d792_docker_db_1
> (3b0c5cf0437b75725d98b732640a6e2efaa84fdcdad46700f8a7665caae23fae):
> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address
> already in use
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
>
> Failed to deploy 'Compose: docker': `docker-compose` process finished
> with exit code 1

Я так понимаю проблема в том, что уже какой-то другой контейнер запущен:
**"WARNING: Host is already in use by another container".**
Но я никаких контейнеров больше не запускал.

Также у меня на компе установлен сервер Postgres + десктопный менеджер DBeaver. Может быть это они как-то мешают, я не в курсе. Просто сначала всё сделал по старинке, а сейчас вот пытаюсь с помощью контейнера.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка? я в Docker новичок....

Comment: код лучше вставлять, как текст, а не картинки

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, OK учту на будущее ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас на компьютере установлен `Postgres` и он запущен на `5432`, то у вас контейнер на этом же порту не запустится, т.к. порт уже занят, вам нужно либо остановить `Postgres`, либо поменять мапинг портов в `docker-compose`.

Например:

```yaml
...
ports:
  - 15432:5432
...
```

Это приведет к тому, что у вас `Postgres` внутри контейнера будет запускаться на `5432` (т.е. ваше приложение сможет к нему подключаться по `db:5432`), а доступен на хост системе будет по `15432`.

Также если вы не планируете подключаться к `Postgres` (контейнер) с хост машини, то маппинг портов, можно вообще убрать, это приведет к тому, что у база будет доступна только внутри сети докера, но не из вне.

Comment: Спасибо! Порт 15432 помог!